# Having trouble setting up discord bot on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, discord.js

I've done all the steps required in heroku to setup a discord bot but i need dependency "discord.js fs". How could i accomplish this?

````
2019-11-27T15:54:52.648918+00:00 app[Worker.1]: [ws] [connection] Clearing heartbeat interval
2019-11-27T15:54:52.649526+00:00 app[Worker.1]: [ws] [connection] Attempted to destroy WebSocket but no connection exists!
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652133+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided.
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652137+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientManager.js:48:41)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652139+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652141+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:210:5)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652143+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.onClose (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:390:10)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652145+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocket.onClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652147+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652149+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocket.emitClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:191:10)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652152+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.socketOnClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:850:15)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652154+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:215:7)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652156+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at net.js:659:12
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652282+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
2019-11-27T15:54:52.652407+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2019-11-27T15:54:52.721072+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 0```
````

Comment: Could you provide what steps you have specifically tried?

Comment: I tried to install it using the console and it was successful but when i redeployed, i was met with the same error

Comment: You probably use Client Secret instead of Token. Try checking this out!